is it haram to take money from the cash without letting my employer know for overtime if they don't pay for the OT as i contracted with my employer?
I'm from a Southeast Asian country. I come to Saudi Arabia at the cost of 15 thousand SAR. It's been 2 years since I started working for a company near Madina. When they hired me, I contracted 8 hours of duty for 1100 SAR. The contract duration was 1 year. After a few months, they started forcing me to sign on a new contract paper, which is 8 hours of duty time for around 685 SAR + 4 hours of overtime for 515 SAR as Saudi Labor Law mandates a specific overtime pay rate. Then they were forcing me to sign on the new paper and telling me IF I DON'T SIGN ON THE NEW PAPER, THEY'LL SEND ME BACK TO MY COUNTRY. Then I signed on the new paper and started working. Now I want to know if I just take money from the cash without knowing my employer for overtime money as I contracted before, which was for 1 year. The money will be haram???
